# Can UDAF's return complex types in SPARK SQL 2.2.0?

Tags: apache-spark

Can UDAF's return complex types? like say a Map with key as an Integer and the value as an Array of strings?

For Example say I have the following **input dataframe**

```
id | name  | amount
-------------------------
1  |  foo  | 10
2  |  bar  | 15
1  |  car  | 20
1  |  bus  | 20
```

and my **target/output data frame** is

```
id | my_sum_along_with_names
-------------------------------------------------------------
1  | Map(key -> 50, value -> [foo, car, bus])
2  | Map(key -> 15, value -> [bar])
```

I am looking for a UDAF solution so I can use it in my raw sql query.

Comment: You cannot have `Map(key -> 50, value -> [foo, car, bus])` in `DataFrame` at all. All values have to be of the same type. If anything it should be struct.

Comment: Aren't all values are same time here? which is array?

Comment: Clearly `array<string>` (`value`) is not the same types as `key` (numeric).

Comment: Key and Value have to be same type? I didn't know that. I thought all keys should be same type say type1 and all values should be of same type say type2..If you are right How come the solution below was able to do it?

Comment: No. Representation in the answer is `Map(50 -> [foo, car, bus])` not `Map(key -> 50, value -> [foo, car, bus])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UDAF` is not required for the requirement you have. It can be achieved simply by using `groupBy`, `agg`, `sum` and `collect_list` *inbuilt functions* and finally using `map` *inbuilt function*.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.groupBy("id").agg(sum("amount").as("key"), collect_list("name").as("value"))
  .select(col("id"), map(col("key"), col("value")).as("my_sum_along_with_names"))
  .show(false)
```

which would result

```
+---+-------------------------------------------+
|id |my_sum_along_with_names                    |
+---+-------------------------------------------+
|1  |Map(50.0 -> WrappedArray( foo,  car,  bus))|
|2  |Map(15.0 -> WrappedArray( bar))            |
+---+-------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for this. The only I asked in terms of UDAF is because I have a custom calculation that I need to do other than sum so I wonder how your solution would change if that is the case?

Comment: it depends on what calculations you have.

Comment: just like how sum operates on a group in the amount column and returns an integer for every group. Please imagine I have a custom function that would operate on a group and returns an integer as well..the custom function in general applies some bitwise operators for all the values in a particular group and returns a integer. Does that makes sense now?

Comment: what I can suggest is collect list for amounts as well and pass it to udf function where you can do bitwise calculation. If you can apply inbuilt function then its even better. So you may accept this answer ask your requirement in another question and I shall help you with that.

Comment: I wonder if I can do `select custom_udf(amount) as custom_calculation, collect_list(name) as my_sum_along_with_names  from df group by id` ?

Comment: udf function work on each rows and not group of rows as collect_list and other aggregate functions. if you want to write udf on group of rows then that is a udaf which is going to be complex. for simplicity just collect the amounts and pass the collected list in udf function and do your calculation. thats all. :)

Comment: got it! It was a typo I meant udaf instead of udf in my previous comment. and sure I can collect as a list and pass it on to udf too but will I be able to collect list for every group? 

`select custom_udf(collect_list(amount)) as custom_calculation, 
 collect_list(name) as my_sum_along_with_names from df group by id`
would this work?

Comment: when I apply group by isn't aggregation function mandatory? How would spark sql know my custom_udf(collect_list(amount)) is an aggregation function? Sorry this is my final question on this.

Comment: you have use custom udf after you do aggregation. As i told you that udf function is applied on each rows and not on group of rows.